# give property name to values in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this function that required selected Ids into an array and the result is this

```
[7950, 7949, 7948, 7947, 7945, 7944, 7943, 7942, 7941, 7938]
```

But now I want to results to be formatted like `[{id: 7950}, {id:7949}]` etc

function

```
this.checked = this.students.filter((student) => student.checked === true).map((student) => student.id);
```

Comment: What is `this.students` here? Share some data related to it.

Comment: yes its data related

Comment: Clue - associative arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply return an object in your `map` function.

```js
const arr = [7950, 7949, 7948, 7947, 7945, 7944, 7943, 7942, 7941, 7938].map(id => ({id}));
console.log (arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could map objects with a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var ids = [7950, 7949, 7948, 7947, 7945, 7944, 7943, 7942, 7941, 7938],
    result = ids.map(id => ({ id }));

console.log(result);
```